# How can I get data from the inverse entity in a ManyToOne relation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've two entities ( `Tarif` and `Hebergement` ). They are associated with a `ManyToOne` relation.

```
// In tarif.php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BookiserFrontBundle\Entity\Hebergement", inversedBy="tarif")
*/
private $hebergement;


// In Hebergement.php
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BookiserFrontBundle\Entity\Tarif", mappedBy="tarif")
*/
private $tarif;
```

If I do in controller:

```
$tarif = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository(Tarif::class)->find($myTarifId);
dump($tarif->getHebergement());
```

It gives me a result but with:

```
$hebergement = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository(Hebergement::class)->find($myHebergementId);
dump($hebergement->getTarif());
```

The collection is empty. My question is : How can I get tarif datas from hebergement ?

I work with Symfony 3.4

Comment: the collection might be empty, because it's not initialized. (check for `initialized` in the dump). calling `->toArray()` on the collection, for example, will initialize it = fetch it

Comment: Look this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123691/symfony-doctrine-joining-a-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: `mappedBy="tarif"` needs to be `mappedBy="hebergement"`